# When rollbacking a migration in rails I get NoMethodError: undefined method `trim' for LL():Rake::Scope::EmptyScope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

When I rollback migrations in rails I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `trim' for LL():Rake::Scope::EmptyScope
```

The migration goes through but it prevents me from running multiple migrations as it crashes after rollbacking.

Here is stack trace:

```
>> rails db:rollback ^2 --trace

** Invoke db:rollback (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute multiverse:load_config
** Execute db:rollback
== 20201007084505 CreateValuation: reverting ==================================
-- drop_table(:valuations)
   -> 0.0030s
== 20201007084505 CreateValuation: reverted (0.0080s) =========================

** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:dump
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `trim' for LL():Rake::Scope::EmptyScope
```

Any ideas? I don't even know where to start.

EDIT:
Migrations code per request.

```
class CreateValuation < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :valuations do |t|
      t.integer :car_id, null: false
      t.integer :value
      t.datetime :date, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please share your migration code so we can try to help

Comment: @MarceloRibeiro Added it :)